# Online Gaussian-elimination solver that produces Latex code of the detailed solution.

Tags: reference-request, math-software, gaussian-elimination

I wonder if there exists an online (free) Gaussian-elimination solver that generates a $\LaTeX$ code describing each steps of the detailed solution, i.e. telling which elementary operation is performed and showing the transformed matrix at each step.

There are many Gaussian-elimination solver (e.g. [this one](http://matrix.reshish.com/gauss-jordanElimination.php) is quite good IMO) but I couldn't find any that produces the associated $\LaTeX$ code.

I know similar stuffs exists (as Latex packages) for long divisions (also polynomial long divisions). See [here](http://cs.brown.edu/about/system/managed/latex/doc/polynom.pdf).

This would be great to generate exercises for students (texing the solution of a non-trivial system is a long and not very funny task).

Comment: I don't know of any, but it should be pretty easy to code one, you just have a traditional solver print to a .txt file and have another program read the output and turn vectors/matrices into \begin{pmatrix} things.

Comment: I'm not saying it is hard to code, but I'd be very happy if such a thing is already implemented (because my experience with programming is that easy or not: it takes always a lot of time). And somehow, I'd be very surprised to be the first one who comes up with this idea.

Comment: Oh I know, my comment was almost purely directed at musing on the problem itself.